# send the reputation values of nodes to the neighbour nodes

Tags: omnet++

I want to send the reputation values of nodes to the neighbour nodes in OMNet++ utilizing Veins. I have installed veins4a. I have done the tictoc and run the veins successfully. Can anybody help me on how to send this type of information in Veins. Should i use extra message but UDP/TCP is not supported in the current version of Veins.

Is it possible to send this message using the `WaveShortMessage.msg` by adding extra information (like extension in this message)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to start might be to modify the existing example, which uses `TraCIDemo11p` as its application and `WaveShortMessage` as the message exchanged between cars. Feel free to add new fields to the message class (just like you did in the Tic Toc tutorial, but now in `WaveShortMessage.msg`) and to implement new ways of how the application reacts to received messages (again, just like in the Tic Toc tutorial, but now in `TraCIDemo11p.cc`).

Comment: to change how TraCIDemo11p reacts upon receiving data, change its [onData](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L50) handler. There is no need to implement another handler to achieve this.